# Multiple instances/sessions of a web app codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am new to backend coding but I am getting the hang of codeigniter. I have deployed the [simple task board application hosted on github](http://oscardias.github.io/Simple-Task-Board/) and everything is fine. As it stands this application uses sessions to create a single dashboard that can be shared by multiple users. I would like to be able to set this up so that a user could register and start their own dashboard. For simplicity it would be good if this new instance or session (not quite sure if I have the terminology right) could share the same database.

So my question is can someone tell me what I need to research in order to develop this? I dont think I have the right terminology to ask google or manuals for what I need.

Comment: look up multitenant database architecture

Comment: Thanks. Looks interesting, but also more complicated than I was hoping for. I dont want to get involved in this if its beyond the scope of what I need. I will keep reading.

Comment: You'll need to have a tenant_id column on everything and check it for so every user will have their own dashboard and cannot see other peoples data

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you to use codeigniter session library and for dashboard, you may be stored much data in session, so use **"Saving Session Data to a Database"**

check this link : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html